# The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini. showing while uploading a theme

Tags: uploads

The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

how to fix this issue?

Comment: Well you either need to change the value of upload_max_filesize in php.ini to be larger than the size of the theme's .zip, or find another way to upload the theme e.g. through a shell prompt and then unzip the .zip into the right place (= /wp-content/themes/<theme name>), or upload the already-unzipped theme directly into place using SFTP or whatever mechanism you have in your control panel.

Comment: How can i resize the php.ini

Comment: It's usually in /etc/php.ini. Depending on how your hosting is set up you might not have permission to edit this file though - you'll typically need to su or sudo to the root user to edit it. If you can't edit this you'll probably have to ask your host provider.

Comment: I'll directly uploaded the zip file on server. and extracted it. now it's working